# Regular expression to extract id from email subject

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

I need to extract the ID from the following email-subject in PHP.

Subject:

> New tour subscription [ALKJ-102] [ID:12345]

The final results should be **12345**

Comment: please. show us, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `/(?<=\[ID:)\d+/` pattern that match digits that is after `[ID:` string.

```
$subject = "New tour subscription [ALKJ-102] [ID:12345]";
preg_match("/(?<=\[ID:)\d+/", $subject, $mat);
echo $mat[0];
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/rDjZc)

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this page to solve it.

My solution was:

```
([\w]*([:])(?<Value>[\w]*))
```

I created you this documented example.

In this example you can directly get the Value named group and use in the code.

```
$test="[ALKJ-102] [ID:12345]";

preg_match('/([\w]*([:])(?<Value>[\w]*))/',$test,$matches);

var_dump($matches['Value']);
```

http://rubular.com/r/uvHvHjZR8R